# Movie about King Tut and an archaeologist

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

In this movie I watched, the protagonist and the antagonist were looking for some artifact, I think it was an emerald tablet with a hole in it. I think the antagonist intended to use this artifact to summon the devil. There is one scene where the antagonist has captured the protagonist and wants to mummify him while alive, but the latter is saved somehow. In another scene, the main characters are either in hell or the Egyptian version of the afterlife, King Tut flies on a set of wings to rescue the main character.

Any idea what the movie is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is [The Curse of King Tut's Tomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_of_King_Tut%27s_Tomb_(2006_film))

> In ancient Egypt, Tutankhamun, the boy pharaoh who is said to have
> died young, was actually sent by the sun god Ra to protect the people
> from the demon Set, who escaped from the Underworld and caused chaos
> in Egypt. With Ra's blessing, Tutankhamun manages to overcome Set and
> keep the demon under control by **breaking an emerald tablet** into four
> pieces and sending the pieces to the far corners of the world.
> However, the tradeoff is that **he must remain in the Underworld**.

[Link to the movie on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpEWaYrYnSQ)

Emerald tablet with a hole in it:
[image: Movie promotional image showing an archaeologist holding up the emerald tablet with a hole in it]

Winged King Tut:
[image: An image showing King Tut with mechanicals wings, brandishing a sword]